# Is it possible to implement Data.Reflection’s trick using type families instead of fundeps?

Tags: haskell

The GHC implementation of [`Data.Reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection/docs/Data-Reflection.html) from the [`reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package uses a trick involving `unsafeCoerce` that takes advantage of the way GHC compiles typeclasses using dictionary passing. The implementation is short, so I can reproduce it in its entirety here:

```
class Reifies s a | s -> a where
  reflect :: proxy s -> a

newtype Magic a r = Magic (forall (s :: *). Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r)

reify :: forall a r. a -> (forall (s :: *). Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r) -> r
reify a k = unsafeCoerce (Magic k :: Magic a r) (const a) Proxy
```

This makes it possible to reify a value at the type level, then reflect it back:

```
ghci> reify (42 :: Integer) (\p -> reflect p) :: Integer
42
```

I was interested in using this technique, but I thought it would be convenient for my purposes to use a type family with `Reifies` rather than a functional dependency, so I attempted to rewrite the implementation using the usual transformation:

```
class Reifies s where
  type Reflects s
  reflect :: Proxy s -> Reflects s

newtype Magic a r = Magic (forall (s :: *). (Reifies s, Reflects s ~ a) => Proxy s -> r)

reify :: forall a r. a -> (forall (s :: *). (Reifies s, Reflects s ~ a) => Proxy s -> r) -> r
reify a k = unsafeCoerce (Magic k :: Magic a r) (const a) Proxy
```

Sadly, however, this no longer works! This changes compilation significantly enough to break the `unsafeCoerce` trick:

```
ghci> reify (42 :: Integer) (\p -> reflect p) :: Integer
2199023255808
```

However, I’m not familiar enough with how GHC works to understand why. Is it possible to implement `Data.Reflection` using an associated type instead of a functional dependency? If so, what needs to change? If not, why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unsafeCoerce` trick takes advantage of the fact that

```
Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r
```

has exactly the same representation, at run-time, as

```
a -> Proxy s -> r
```

By enlarging the constraint to `(Reifies s a, a ~ Reflects s)`, you violate this critical assumption. There are several ways to fix this. Here's one:

```
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, PolyKinds, KindSignatures,
       RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators #-}
module TFReifies where
import Data.Proxy
import Unsafe.Coerce
import Data.Type.Equality

class Reifies s a where
  type Reflects s :: *
  reflect' :: proxy s -> a

reflect :: (Reifies s a, a ~ Reflects s) => proxy s -> a
reflect = reflect'


newtype Magic a r = Magic (forall (s :: *). (Reifies s a) => Proxy s -> r)

reify' :: forall a r. a -> (forall (s :: *). (Reifies s a) => Proxy s -> r) -> r
reify' a k = unsafeCoerce (Magic k :: Magic a r) (const a) Proxy

reify :: forall a r. a -> (forall (s :: *). (Reifies s a, a ~ Reflects s) => Proxy s -> r) -> r
reify a f = reify' a (\(p :: Proxy s) -> case unsafeCoerce Refl :: a :~: Reflects s of Refl -> f p)
```

---

Here's a version closer to yours:

```
class Reifies s where
  type Reflects s :: *
  reflect :: proxy s -> Reflects s

newtype Magic a r = Magic (forall (s :: *). (Reifies s) => Proxy s -> r)

reify :: forall a r. a -> (forall (s :: *). (Reifies s, a ~ Reflects s) => Proxy s -> r) -> r
reify a f = reify' a (\(p :: Proxy s) -> case unsafeCoerce Refl :: a :~: Reflects s of Refl -> f p)
  where
    -- This function is totally bogus in other contexts, so we hide it.
    reify' :: forall a r. a -> (forall (s :: *). (Reifies s) => Proxy s -> r) -> r
    reify' a k = unsafeCoerce (Magic k :: Magic a r) (const a) Proxy
```

Comment: After I wrote this question, I peeked at the core and discovered, to my surprise, that type equalities have runtime witnesses, at least at the core level. Is there some information somewhere about how type equality witnesses work? Can I (unsafely) provide something else in place of the equality witness? Changing my code ever so slightly to `unsafeCoerce (Magic k :: Magic a r) (const a) () Proxy` works, but I’m afraid it might not always work.

Comment: @AlexisKing, that's a good question to which I do not know the answer.

Comment: @AlexisKing, another option (I think) might be to make `reflect'` return a GADT giving evidence that `a ~ Reflects s`. I haven't worked through that yet.

Comment: @AlexisKing, Actually, I might have an answer... Look at "System F with Type Equality Coercions". Find a version with the post-publication appendix. That probably explains things to people like you (and unlike me) who understand all that type theory stuff.

Comment: I think you gravely overestimate how much I understand what I’m doing. :) But thanks, I’ll take a look.

Comment: @AlexisKing, you wrote a type checker in `syntax-case`. That's nothing to sneeze at.